# Android Studio Emulator Crashing on Ubuntu

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu, android-emulator

I can't get the emulator to work on my ubuntu.
I'm getting this error when I try to start it and it happens on several android versions, olds and new ones.

[image: android studio emulator crash report]

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I had to update my GPU drivers, after that the emulator worked as expected.